# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'engine'

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.6

I've been trying to load data from my table and suddenly i was facing an attribute error. I don't know why but i was not able to fix this.

```
def load_titles_data(db):
    sql = """
        SELECT 
            id_titles,
            content_type
        FROM public.titles
    """
    titles_df = pd.read_sql(sqlalchemy.text(sql), db.engine)
    return titles_df
```

I'm using a postgres database

```
>>> titles_df = load_titles_data(db)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in load_titles_data
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'engine'
```

Please help me solve that error, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `db`? Apparently you think it is something else but it actually is a tuple. You need to figure out why it is not what you think it is.

Comment: Seems like the `db` you give in argument is actually a tuple. What is in `db` ? how do you obtain it before giving it to `load_titles_data` ?

Comment: If i was a betting man i would say you declare `db` somewhere but have a trailing comma `,` at the end of that line making it a tuple